# Efficient Row Sum of Factorized Matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am currently computing the row sums of a reduced rank factored matrix by reconstructing a row subset of the original (approximated) matrix.

The matrix was factored using SVD: A -> U, S, V -> U, SxV = W So the reconstruction is SxW ~ A (using the desired rows in S).

How can I do this without having to reconstruct SxW, and then sum over the columns? I believe it is possible using the reduced rank matrices U, W.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
\begin{equation}
A = U \Sigma V^T
\end{equation} 
denote the singular value decomposition of the matrix $A$, where $U^TU = V^TV = I$ and $\Sigma$ is the diagonal matrix
\begin{equation}
\Sigma = \text{diag}( \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dotsc, \sigma_n)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1 \ge \sigma_2 \ge \dotsc, \ge \sigma_n \ge 0.
\end{equation}
The singular value decomposition can be written as
\begin{equation}
A = \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k u_k v_k^T
\end{equation}
where $u_k$ and $v_k$ are the columns of $U$ and $V$ respectively, the so-called left and right singular values. If there is positive integer $r > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sigma_r \gg \sigma_r \ge 0
\end{equation}
then it becomes attractive approximate $A$ using a truncated singular value decomposition, say,
\begin{equation}
A_r = \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_k u_k v_k^T
\end{equation}
The question of computing the row sum of the matrix $A$ is equivalent to computing the matrix vector product
\begin{equation}
y = A \mathbf{1}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector where every component is a copy of the real number $1$. Using the truncated singular value decomposition we can now approximate $y$ with the vector
\begin{equation}
y_r = A_r \mathbf{1} =  \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k u_k v_k^T \mathbf{1} = \sum_{k=1}^r u_k ( \sigma_k (v_k^T \mathbf{1})
\end{equation}
The last expression must be considered with great care as the terms have been reordered and the parentheses have placed to indicate how the expression should be evaluated numerically. Each inner product collapses in to a sum and requires $n-1$ additions, then there is a single scalar multiplication with $\sigma_k$, followed by another $n$ multiplications to account for the scaling of the vector $u_k$. This is a total of $2n$ arithmetic operations for each term. The $r$ terms have to be added together using another $n(r-1)$ additions. The total flop count is less than $3nr$ operations for the entire computation. This is a significant saving provided that $r$ is much less than $n$. If we explicitly formed the matrix $A_r$ then the row sum computation would require $O(n^2)$ operations apart from the cost of building $A_r$.

It is vital to remember that any approximation is useless without at least an error bound or, better still, a reliable error estimate. In our case we have
\begin{equation}
\|A - A_r\|_2 = \sigma_{r+1}
\end{equation}
which immediately implies the error bound
\begin{equation}
\| y - y_r\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \sigma_{r+1}
\end{equation}
We conclude that the singular values have to decay quite rapidly for this technique to be both profitable and accurate.